# soql picklist toLabel apex

Tags: apex, soql, picklist, label

I want to get label of picklist from soql and use it in my apex code to do some logic. For example following code gives me error

> Compile failure on line 7, column 18: Invalid field labelType for
>   SObject  FieldSet__c

In below code how do I get the label for picklist in my apex code.Thanks for your help and time.

```
List<FieldSet__c> fieldSets = [SELECT toLabel(Type__c) labelType,Type__c
FROM FieldSet__c];

for (FieldSet__c fieldSet : fieldSets) 
{
    System.debug(fieldSet.labelType);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access it by  sobject get method like: `fieldSet.get('labelType')` and you can select both label and picklistvalue in single query.